# URL Redirection to Untrusted Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, security

I have below code in service.ts file and VeraCode code scan fails

Flaws by CWE ID:
URL Redirection to Untrusted Site ('Open Redirect') (CWE ID 601)(16 flaws)
Description
A web application accepts a untrusted input that specifies a link to an external site, and uses that link to generate a redirect. This enables phishing attacks.

Please help me to fix this

Service.ts:

```
public exportReviews(searchReviewData: SurveillanceReviewSearchViewModel): Observable<SurveillanceReviewSearchViewModel> {
    this._urlSurveillanceDetails = this.baseHref +"/ReviewProfile/ExportReviews";
    const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post<SurveillanceReviewSearchViewModel>(this._urlSurveillanceDetails, searchReviewData, { headers: headers }); // flaw identified on this line
  }

public getReviewsBySearchSessionId(searchsessionId): Observable<SurveillanceReviewSearchViewModel> {
    this._urlSurveillanceDetails = this.baseHref + "/ReviewProfile/SearchReviewsBySessionId" + '?searchsessionId=' + searchsessionId;
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this._urlSurveillanceDetails = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this._urlSurveillanceDetails));
    return this.http.post<SurveillanceReviewSearchViewModel>(this._urlSurveillanceDetails, headers); // flaw identified on this line
  }
```

Comment: Ensure you sanitize the data in `searchReviewData` before passing it along.

Comment: @RichardBarker - i tried sanitize  in "getReviewsBySearchSessionId" funtion but still im getting same issue in next line.I updated the code in question section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a false positive. The request url is not built from untrusted user input or user input in general. Static code analysis is not perfect and you'll experience false positives all over the place.

Comment: I believe this to be true except that OP is passing user input to that service which may open up other attack vectors.

Comment: @RichardBarker Yes, he's passing a untrusted input as body, but not as a URL. Unlike the URL, controlling the body is usually not considered a security vulnerability unless there are specific other circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

You can use encodeURI() method to encode the parameters which are getting detected under CWE-601, it could be false positive as others have mentioned, but encodeURI() wraps the parameters so that Veracode doesn't detect it as a security flaw.